# Magento 2: Update database table add new columns like created_at and updated_at from module

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, upgradeschema

> UpgradeScema.php

```
<?php
namespace Lucent\MegaMenu\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Gallery;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media\ImageEntryConverter;

/**
 * Upgrade the Catalog module DB scheme
 */
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        //if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.2.0', '<')) {

            $tableName = $setup->getTable('lucent_megamenu');
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn('creation_at',Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,null,['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],'Creation Time')
            ->setComment('MegaMenu Table');
      //  }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way..

```
namespace Lucent\MegaMenu\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
          $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('lucent_megamenu'),
                'created_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
                'Created At'
            );

            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('lucent_megamenu'),
                'updated_at',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
                    'Updated At'
            );
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**Note: check the Extension version (change the version as per your requirements) of the extension in the `module.xml` file to run the upgrade script while `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.**

Comment: Thank you very much bro. I also found solution.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try with the below code.

```
namespace Lucent\MegaMenu\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('lucent_megamenu'),
                'creation_at',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    'length' => 1000,
                    [
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT
                    ],
                    'comment' => 'Creation Time'
                ]
            );
            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('lucent_megamenu'),
                'updated_at',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    'length' => 1000,
                    [
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE
                    ],
                    'comment' => 'Updation Time'
                ]
            );
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Also, please check the version (change the version as per your requirements) of the extension in the `module.xml` file to run the upgrade script while `setup:upgrade`.

***Hope it helps!!!***